# maven dependencies in eclipse4 rcp project

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp

I've created an eclipse 4 application project named base and ran it using its base.product. After making this project a maven project, I added a dependency to the apache commons-io library in order to use file functions like this

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("se presiono "+btnNewButton.getText());
            File file = new File("mi archivossss.txt");

            try {
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "prueba de archvio");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

When I tried to ran the project I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
at base.parts.PrincipalPart$1.mouseDown(PrincipalPart.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:192)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:164)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils cannot be found by base_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Therefore I configured the dependencies manually and this works, so I know that it is a configuration issue related to maven dependencies. However I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: How did you run the project?

Comment: right button over my project.product file and run as eclipse application

Comment: Does eclipse show a "Maven Dependencies" library in the project?

Comment: yes, eclispse show it and the library was downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct dependency is in your Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure the m2e plugin is installed in Eclipse.

In Eclipse, select your project folder and right click. Go to the Maven choice in the popup and choose "Update Project" then "OK" in the next dialog. This is how Maven puts the class on your machine in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that you're running this project as an *Eclipse Application*.

Assuming then that the project you are trying to add the maven dependencies to is an Eclipse plug-in.

This doesn't work, since m2e cannot handle plug-in dependencies.

In order to be able to run your product within Eclipse (i.e. *Run as...* > *Eclipse Application*), you need to add the dependencies as [Plug-in Dependencies](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm) from the plug-in manifest (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`).

Alternatively, you can build you product using [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/).